# Data from multiple ArrayLists not not being pushed correctly

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, kotlin

I am trying to push data from 2 `ArrayList`s (declared inside a `Fragment`) to an `AlertDialog` containing multiple tabs. The tab names (`myDialogTitles`) appear correctly but for some reason, the content underneath each tab does not, and always seems to show data from only the first item in the `ArrayList` (`myDialogDescriptions`). What needs to change so that the content underneath each tab displays the correct text accordingly?

**Expected output**

- Tab A -> Description A
- Tab B -> Description B
- Tab C -> Description C

**Current output**

- Tab A -> Description A
- Tab B -> Description A
- Tab C -> Description A

**Fragment class**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view

        mRecyclerView = v!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recyclerview)

        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val myList = ArrayList<Item>()

        val myDialogTitles = ArrayList<String>()
        myDialogTitles.add("Tab A")
        myDialogTitles.add("Tab B")
        myDialogTitles.add("Tab C")

        val myDialogDescriptions = ArrayList<String>()
        myDialogDescriptions.add("Description A")
        myDialogDescriptions.add("Description B")
        myDialogDescriptions.add("Description C")


        val mAdapter = MyAdapter(myList, childFragmentManager)

        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

**Dialog class**

```
class TabbedDialog(private val facilitiesList: ArrayList<Facility>,
                   private val myDialogTitles: ArrayList<String>,
                   private val myDialogDescriptions: ArrayList<String>) : DialogFragment() {
    lateinit var customView: View

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return customView
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val b = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setIconAttribute(R.attr.imgNight)
            .setTitle(facilitiesList[id].textFacilityADialogTitle)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok)) { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }

        customView = activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)

        val tabLayout = customView.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.mTabLayout)
        val viewPager = customView.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.mViewPager)

        val adapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        for (item in myDialogTitles) {
            adapter.addFragment(item, FragmentDialogContent.createInstance(myDialogDescriptions[id]))
        }

        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        b.setView(customView)
        return b.create()
    }
}
```

**View Pager Adapter class**

```
class MyViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT){
    private val titleList : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    private val fragmentList : MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    fun addFragment(title: String, fragment: Fragment){
        titleList.add(title)
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return titleList[position]
    }
}
```

**Item data class**

```
data class Item (val myDialogTitle: String, val myDialogDescription: String)
```

Comment: Please give more details. Where is `FragmentDialogContent`'s defination?

Comment: @djhs16 In the `TabbedDialog` class. Near the bootom of the `onCreateDialog` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your for loop in `TabbedDialog` from

```
for (item in myDialogTitles) {
    adapter.addFragment(item, FragmentDialogContent.createInstance(myDialogDescriptions[id]))
}
```

with

```
myDialogTitles.forEachIndexed { index, item->
    adapter.addFragment(item, FragmentDialogContent.createInstance(myDialogDescriptions[index]))
}
```

Issue is you are using `id` as index.